# How to solve $1+a-b^2\frac{x}{|x|^5}=0?$, where $a$ denotes the integral media of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$. How to find the solutions of the equation
$$1+a-b^2\frac{x}{|x|^5}=0?$$
Here $a$ denotes the integral media of a function (I don't know, in general it could have a negative value,too?).

If $a>0$, I have that $x=|b|^{1/2} (1+a)^{1/4}$, since it could be only $x>0$.

Could someone help me with the case $a<0$? (If it makes sense to consider that case). I don't know how to proceed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can proceed similarly as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4362407/42969. There you had $\frac{x}{|x|^3} = something $ and here you have $\frac{x}{|x|^5}= something$

Comment: Re the comment of @MartinR, you are interrogating the wrong expression.  Instead of questioning whether $a$ is positive or negative, you should be questioning whether $(1+a)$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Consider the general equation $\frac{x}{|x|^k} = c$. First note that $x$ must have the same sign as $c$. Then compute the absolute values ...

Comment: But in general, it would be possible fir a function to have a negative integral media?

Comment: @MartinR I used your comments and I found that, in the case of the specific problem I asked, the solution would be $x=\sqrt{|b|} (1+a)|1+a|^{-5/4}$. Could you please tell me if I am right?

Comment: @C.Bishop: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us solve the more general equation
$$ \tag{$*$}
 \frac{x}{|x|^k} = c
$$
where $c$ is a non-zero real number and $k$ is a positive integer. (In your case is $k=5$ and $c=(1+a)/b^2$.)

$x$ has the same sign as $c$, and taking absolute values we get
$$
 \frac{|x|}{|x|^k} = |c| \implies |x| = \frac{1}{|c|^{1/(k-1)}} \, .
$$
It follows that the solution of $(*)$ is
$$
 x = \frac{\operatorname{sign}(c)}{|c|^{1/(k-1)}} \, .
$$
Using $\operatorname{sign}(c) = c/|c|$ the solution  can be alternatively expressed as
$$
 x = \frac{c}{|c|^{k/(k-1)}} \, .
$$
In your case that is
$$
 x = \frac{1+a}{b^2} \left| \frac{b^2}{1+a}\right|^{5/4}
 = \frac{(1+a)|b|^{1/2}}{|1+a|^{5/4}} \, .
$$